# What do I need to do to get ready for 2 new SSDs?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

I have 2 OCZ Agility 60 GB drives shipping to me in a few days. I picture using one as a boot drive, the other for applications, and a 3rd 1TB traditional hard drive for music, pictures, etc. However, I have read several places that these OCZ Agility drives need some special steps to install properly.

What do I need to do in Windows/BIOS to properly set up these new SSDs?

Comment: what operating system? also, what hardware, e.g. Dell or Toshiba or ?

Comment: Best info will be found at the OCZ forums. See the "OCZ Flash Support And Discussion Forum" section

http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/forum.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your question at face value, you don't need to do anything; the system will just see them as regular hard drives.

It is important to make sure your partitions are aligned correctly to the blocks (Windows Vista and 7 do this by default but XP does NOT, I'll assume you're not using XP though) and it's required to run in AHCI mode for TRIM support - you change this in the BIOS, generally under the SATA configurations.  The drives will WORK without doing either of these things though.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you didn't list many factors, I am going to make BIG assumptions here.

**Assumption 1:**
You are formatting your SSDs and running say Windows 7 on it.  I would suggest RAID 0 setup for both SSD's you would get 120GB of space that way and 2x the performance for Reads/Writes

**Assumption 2:**
Your Motherboard actually supports SSD / AHCI and RAID functionality

**Assumption 3:**
You know how to setup RAID 0 on your motherboard if condition is true for the above.

Keep in mind RAID is different from (assumption) what you are used to (non raid setups).

Hope that at least gives you some ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: I'd be inclined to avoid RAIDing SSDs, unless there is a very specific need for high *sequential* read speeds. And I don't think it's totally accurate to state that RAID-0 gives SSDs 2x the performance. For example, the SSDs' random write speed is likely to decline over time (especially due to the lack of TRIM when RAIDed, but this also depends on the SSD manufacturer and the OS).